# Asymptotic distribution of intraclass correlation

Tags: distributions, asymptotics, intraclass-correlation, f-distribution

Consider the random effects ANOVA model below (notation based on Snijders and Bosker, 1999), where $j$ represents a group and $i$ an individual:

$$
Y_{ij} = \mu + U_j + R_{ij}, \qquad var(Y_{ij}) = \tau^2 + \sigma^2
$$

The intraclass correlation coefficient is estimated as

$$
\hat\rho = \frac{\hat\tau^2}{\hat\tau^2 + \hat\sigma^2},
$$

so $\hat\tau^2$ corresponds to the between-group variance and

$$
\hat\sigma^2 = S^2_{within} \\
\hat\rho^2 = S^2_{between} - \frac{S^2_{within}}{n},
$$

where $n$ is the group size (let's just assume all groups have equal size).

The standard error of $\hat\rho^2$ for equal group sizes is given by

$$
\mathit{SE}(\hat\rho) = (1 - \rho)(1 + (n - 1) \rho)\sqrt{\frac{2}{n(n - 1)(N - 1)}},
$$

where $N$ is the number of groups.

A common test for group differences is given by the $F$-statistic below, where

$$
F = \frac{n S^2_{between}}{S^2_{within}}.
$$

I know that $F \sim F(N - 1, M - N)$, where $M$ is the total sample size across groups, but **what is the asymptotic distribution of $\hat\rho$?**

For what it's worth, $\hat\rho$  and $\hat\tau^2$ can also be calculated as functions of $F$:

$$
\hat\tau^2 = \frac{S^2_{within}}{n}(F - 1) \\
\hat\rho = \frac{F - 1}{F + n - 1}.
$$

So it looks like basically $\hat\rho$ is a function of two transformed $F$-distributed random variables, but that's as far as I can go right now.